# Test CRUD Operation while mocking static PreparedStatement method within the method

Tags: java, mysql, junit, mockito, powermock

My original CRUD Method generates a Prepared Statement and sets the strings based on the parameters given.

```
public class StatementUtility {
...
    public static PreparedStatement getFoo(String bar, Connection conn) {
        String query = "SELECT Foo FROM BarTable WHERE Bar = ?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, bar);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            ..
        }
        return pstmt;
    }
...
}
```

In this Statement the Database which I use is set. I created however a TestDB within my MySQL Server where I would like to test a delete Method:

```
public static String deleteFoo(List<String> input) {
    Connection conn = driver.connectCustomerDB(input);
    try(PreparedStatement pstmt = StatementUtility.getFoo(String someString, conn)) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Here is my Test so far

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StatementUtility.class)
public class DBConnectionBTBAdminTest {


    @Test
    public void deleteTest() {

        List<String> testInput = new ArrayList<>();
        testInput.add("hello");
        testInput.add("World");

        Driver driver = new Driver();
        Connection conn = driver.connectCustomerDB(testInput);

        String query = "FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar";

        try {
            //try mocking the Method within
            BDDMockito.given(StatementUtility.getFoo(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), any(Connection.class))).willReturn(conn.prepareStatement(stringBuilder.toString()));
            //call the method I want to test
            SomeClass.deleteCategory(testInput, emptyArray);
            ...
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is a Nullpointer Exception in the Method where I create the PreparedStatement originally, but that is not the point as I do not want to get into this Method at all, but stub it.

I also tried using Mockito instead of BDDMockito (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116014/8830232)
and using the real values instead of ArgumentMatchers.*

I also tried some other stuff like mocking the Connection

Currently I am using *JUnit@4.12*, *Mockito@2.13.0*, *powermock@1.7.1*

> EDIT:
>   For @glytching answer to work I had to downgrade mockito from 2.x to 1.x. >Dont forget to adjust powermock dependencies in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `@PrepareForTest(StatementUtility.class)` (which tells PowerMock to prepare this class for testing) you have to enable static mocking for all methods of `StatementUtility`. You do this by invoking ...

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StatementUtility.class);
```

... in your test before you attempt to set any expectations on that mock.

For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StatementUtility.class)
public class DBConnectionBTBAdminTest {


    @Test
    public void deleteTest() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StatementUtility.class);

        List<String> testInput = new ArrayList<>();
        testInput.add("hello");
        testInput.add("World");

        Driver driver = new Driver();
        Connection conn = driver.connectCustomerDB(testInput);

        String query = "FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar";

        try {
           BDDMockito.given(StatementUtility.getFoo(...)).willReturn(...);

            ...
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Your suggestion threw an error. However after using google I downgraded Mockito and it works. However now my Problem is that I have different Connections and therefore I cant execute my query. But you answered my question so thanks!!